# Single Crystal Growing and Orientation (Silicon) using Czochralski Process

Tags: semiconductors

I'm working on small bibliographic research on photovoltaic panels, and I have chemistry background. I have confusion on crystallization (Czochralski method) imposed by the seed and following specific direction (111) or (100, etc.

1-Are all facets of the seed have the same lattice plane, meaning if you want (100) crystal a seed with all facets being (100) must be dipped into the melt?

2- What differences between directions in terms of crystal growing?

3- When crystallization is finished following (100) for example does the pure silicon maintain the original lattice structure of diamond?

[image]

4- In the Czochralski process, doping element is added to the melt. Why would the dopant sticks uniformly to the new structure or how to make sure it does that?

I appreciate practical details on direction of growing.

Thank you

Comment: While the Czochralski process is used in electrical engineering, I'm not sure this is the right site for this question; is there a materials or metallurgical SE?

Comment: Re 4. The dopant is homogeneously distributed throughout the melt, and the crystalisation process automatically incorporates it into the lattice structure as the crystal is pulled from the melt.